# Razor View is passing wrong Id to OnPost method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I am using Asp.net Core .Net 5 Web app with Razor pages and Identity.
I want to build a Role Manager page for Admin, but when assigning role to a user the passed roleId from View doesn't match the roleId that I passed into View.
Here is my Model

```
public class RoleManagerModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public RoleManagerModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }


    public ApplicationUser UserToChangeRole { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public IdentityRole RoleToAssign { get; set; }
    public static string FirstID { get; set; }
    public static string SecondId { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        Users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
        Roles = await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
        FirstID = Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "Admin").Id;

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string userId)
    {
        UserToChangeRole = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        SecondId = RoleToAssign.Id;
        if(FirstID == SecondId)
        {
            string Gogo = "true";
        }
        var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(RoleToAssign.Id);
        if (UserToChangeRole == null)
            RedirectToPage("/Identity/NotFound");
        if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(RoleToAssign.Name))
        {
           await  _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(UserToChangeRole, RoleToAssign.Name);
        }

        Users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
        Roles = await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();

        return Page();
    }
```

And here is the form in my view.

```
 <!--Roles-->
            <td>
                <form method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Roles"></label>
                        <select class="form-control" asp-for="RoleToAssign">
                            @foreach (var role in Model.Roles)
                            {
                                <option value="@role.Id">@role.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>

                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Assign</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="@user.Id" />
                </form>

            </td>
```

As you can see in the Post method I perform a check if passed and received roleIds match. They don't. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Where the code are you trying to get roleId from select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to page model

```
 [BindProperty]
 public int RoleToAssignId { get; set; }
```

and view

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="RoleToAssignId">
 @foreach (var role in Model.Roles)
 {
  <option value="@role.Id">@role.Name</option>
 }
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did work! Only Role Id is a string. :), Sorry I cannot upvote your answer, need to pump up my reputation.